# How to expect an exact mock as an argument of a method call, and not any mock of the same class, in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

In the example below (using PHP 7.3 ans PHPUnit 7.5.1), I have two mocks of the same class. I want to expect one of the two mocks as an argument in a method call. But the expectation seems to be satisfied if I call the method with the other mock.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $mock1 = $this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)->getMock();
        $mock2 = $this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)->getMock();
        /** @var MockObject|ArrayObject $mock3 */
        $mock3 = $this->getMockBuilder(ArrayObject::class)->setMethods(['append'])->getMock();

        $this->assertEquals($mock1, $mock2); // OK
        $this->assertNotSame($mock1, $mock2); // OK

        $mock3->expects($this->once())->method('append')->with($mock1); // OK

        // However I pass $mock2 instead of $mock1 !
        $mock3->append($mock2);

        // I would need something like :
        // $mock3->expects($this->once())->method('append')->withSameAs($mock1); // Not OK
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling the append function on the mocked object so it wont work as you expect it to. No matter what you put in the `with` function it should pass (in this case).

Comment: @RichieHughes : No, if I pass a string, a boolean, an integer, a new stdClass(), or a mock of another class, the test fails.

Comment: answer incoming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you wanted is to call the `$this->identicalTo` function in the `with` function. That'll verify that the correct object has been passed. If you update the code to pass in the `$mock1` it should fail because the objects aren't the same

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    class ExampleTest extends TestCase
    {
        public function testExample()
        {
            $mock1 = $this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)->getMock();
            $mock2 = $this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)->getMock();
            /** @var MockObject|ArrayObject $mock3 */
            $mock3 = $this->getMockBuilder(ArrayObject::class)
                ->setMethods(['append'])->getMock();

            $mock3->expects($this->once())->method('append')->with($this->identicalTo($mock2)); // OK
            $mock3->append($mock2);

        }
    }
```

**Other Example:**

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $mock1 = $this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)->getMock();
        $mock2 = $this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)->getMock();
        /** @var MockObject|ArrayObject $mock3 */
        $mock3 = $this->getMockBuilder(ArrayObject::class)
            ->setMethods(['append'])->getMock();  

        $class = new ExampleClass($mock3);
        $mock3->expects($this->once())->method('append')->with($this->identicalTo($mock2)); // OK
        $class->appendObject($mock2);

    }
}

class ExampleClass
{
    private $array;

    public function __construct(ArrayObject $array)
    {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function appendObject($stdClass)
    {
        $this->array->append($stdClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! The key was to do `with(identicalTo($mock1))` instead of just `with($mock1)`. I Just changed it in my example code and it works as I expected. On the other side I didn't understand why I sould not call the mocked method directly ? Can you explain that a bit more or remove that from your answer so I can mark it as accepted ? Furthermore it was just a trick to make the example as simple as possible.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include both ways. The issue with calling the mocked function directly is you're not actually testing any of the code in the `append` function. If the append function changes (albeit unlikely) you're test won't break - With the `ExampleClass` I made if we modify the `$stdClass` variable before calling the `append` function the test will break. I guess it doesn't really matter if you're using PHP Classes, just a good to know :)

Comment: Ok, I understand but it was not necessary to answer my question. My real use case is way more complicated, I used PHP Classes and called the mocked method directly in the example code to get it as simple a possible.